# Nginx 301 Redirect for folders

Tags: nginx

I am moving to a new site and the folder path has slightly changed. 
Old Path: /forms/somepdf.pdf
New Path: /uploads/forms/somepdf.pdf

Note that there are sub folders in the forms folder that contain pdf documents as well. I also have an html page in /forms. So normally this would work:

```
rewrite ^/(forms.*) /uploads/$1 permanent;
```

But this makes my forms html page error 404. So, I only want to do the redirect if the filename ends with .pdf and the requested URL starts with "/forms". This is what I have so far, but it is not quite working:

```
rewrite ^/(forms.*)\.pdf /uploads/$1/\.pdf last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I played with it a little more and this seems to work:

```
rewrite ^/(forms.*)\.pdf /uploads/$1.pdf permanent;
```

If you have a better solution please let me know. Thanks